# What format and codecs to use for PS3?

Tags: audio, codec, audio-quality, quality

i have edited a video with Open Shot. However when exporting and trying to watch via PS3 the results end up unsatisfying.

I managed to figure out that the video is displayed fine as MP4 with libx264 Codec but i cannot get audio right. Neither aac nor ac3 codec produce satisfying results. Although sound is played it sounds really annoying, to me like the bass is completely broken. I use the highest quality, 2 Channels and a sampling rate of 48000.

Can anybody help me to get a satisfying result?

BTW VLC Player has no problems with neither of the setups i used for PS3.

Comment: The PS3 doesn't alter your video (to be precise: it can't alter your video). What's more likely the problem is an incorrect configuration of your TV/monitor which results in faulty downsampling. ([Read this for more info](http://www.howtogeek.com/218949/htg-explains-why-the-dialogue-on-your-hdtv-is-too-quiet/))

Comment: Okay thanks for the comment. I'll take a look. But initially i had the problem that either video or audio wasn't playing at all and using forward/backward didn't work. So i thought i had a problem with the codecs used. Btw Windows Media Player couldn't play it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The PS3 is very picky on what it plays and what not. I had the same problem as you (again with an OpenShot video)

Solutions

1)Use http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/ that automatically transcodes to formats for PS3

2)Convert your existing video to PS3 format with https://handbrake.fr/